# MVC4 + EF5: field of type Bit doesnt get updated in Database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, entity-framework-5

i have read a lot about a problem appearing with the change from ObjectContext to DbContext concerning the update mechanism.

But unfortunatelly this tips didnt solved my problem.

So i start a short summary whats my environment:

- VS2012
- MS SQL Express 2008 R2 (v10.50)
- .NET 4.0
- MVC4 (Internet Application Template)
- EF5

Since i use the CodeFirst approach, i extended the UserProfile table with an simple bool field and called the **update-database** accordingly.

```
[Required]
public bool IsEmailApproved { get; set; }
```

When i search in the DB Context and find a user:

```
UserProfile user = ctx.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.SomeField == Id);
```

the **Entity.State** is **Unmodified**, like it should be.

Then i start updating:

```
user.UserName = DateTime.Now.ToString();
user.IsEmailApproved = true;
```

and the **State** changes immediatelly to **Modified** - also nothing special.

But on the

```
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

the database just receives the text field update, not the BIT udpate.

Can anybody help me out with an explanation or a hint, what i make wrong?
Because im almost sure, that the mistake is on my side, otherwise i would have found exact the same questions here...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the state become Modified if *only* IsEmailApproved is set?

Comment: And double checking the column has definitely been generated in the DB as a non-nullable bit?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz: also yes

Comment: **but** it seems that the core of the problem is the Default Value for BIT/bool datatypes. i couldnt manage it, that the package manager will create the default value in the database, even with the **[DefaultValue(false)]** Attribute. My solution was to run a SQL file in the Seed method, and there it seems that i made a mistake, i added a Constraint, it seems that blocked the field to be updated. 
my new solution: manually update the Initial migration file (you can provide the default value like this: **IsEmailApproved = c.Boolean(nullable: false, **defaultValue: false),**

Comment: This comes to my next question: How can i specify via Attributes the DefaultValue of fields? Or is this not possible?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @user3013119: [DefaultValue()] is for the Property Pane in Visual Studio, not for DB generation - I don't think anyway.

Comment: @user3013119: Question 2 - thats where `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` comes in - giving you must more flexibility around the mapping. It will still generate the database in the same way.

Comment: Thank you very much for info and the the hint.
martin fka user3013119